# How do you make remove_column reversible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a migration that removes a column:

```
def change
  remove_column :foos, :bar, :boolean
end
```

When I try to `rake db:rollback` that migration, I get the following error:

```
remove_column is only reversible if given a type.
```

The [ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) documentation says that the following is the signature for `remove_column`:

```
remove_column(table_name, column_name, type, options)
```

So my type in this case should be `:boolean`, and I expect that migration to be reversible. What am I missing?

I can certainly break this out into an `up` and `down` migration to avoid this problem, but I'd like to understand why the `change` syntax isn't working in this case.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.1.2 in this case, and that matches the version listed in the documentation.

Comment: def up; remove_column :foos, :bar, :boolean; end; for the migrate and rollback will call down.
def down; add_column :foos, :bar, :boolean; end;

Comment: I have this irreversible migration problem as well, and I have already ran rake:db migrate.  I can't rollback and edit, so I'm thinking I'll just delete with rails destroy migration migration_name and redo the migration with the column_type.  I'll let you know how it turns out

Comment: @tomb ah I am more than 2 years late and I think the steps you mentioned must have messed up your database even more ): I hope you managed to resolve it all. That's not how you do it.

Comment: @ARK better late than never? I did manage to resolve it, and posted my steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061650/1072655

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Simply adding the 3rd argument (the column's :type) to the `remove_column` method makes that migration reversible. So the OP's original code actually did work, as in:

```
remove_column :foos, :bar, :boolean
```

The rest of this answer was an attempt to discover why this method would not have been working, but the OP ended up getting it to work.

---

I see somewhat contrary info in the documentation for [ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html):

> Some commands like **remove_column** cannot be reversed. If you care to define how to move up and down in these cases, you should define the up and down methods as before.
>
> For a list of commands that are reversible, please see ActiveRecord::Migration::CommandRecorder.

And this from [ActiveRecord::Migration::CommandRecorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration/CommandRecorder.html):

> ActiveRecord::Migration::CommandRecorder records commands done during a migration and knows how to reverse those commands. The CommandRecorder knows how to invert the following commands:
>
> add_column
>
> add_index
>
> add_timestamps
>
> create_table
>
> create_join_table
>
> remove_timestamps
>
> rename_column
>
> rename_index
>
> rename_table

Anyway, it appears that this documentation is out of date... Digging into [the source on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e1d4673102f7c4e58964a6de864402ae9a615688/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb#L128):

The method that's giving you grief is:

```
def invert_remove_column(args)
  raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration, "remove_column is only reversible if given a type." if args.size <= 2
  super
end
```

---

I gave this a shot... setup a migration on my Rails 4.1.2 app and the migration worked both ways -- up and down. Here was my migration:

```
class TestRemoveColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :contacts, :test, :boolean
  end
end
```

I also tried with the `:boolean` argument missing and got the same error as you're talking about. Are you sure you're on the final version of Rails 4.1.2 -- not one of the release candidates? If you are, I'd suggest putting a `binding.pry` into the Rails source for the `invert_remove_column` method to inspect the arguments list and see what's going on. To do so, just run `bundle open activerecord` and then explore to: *lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:128*.

Comment: I had some wires crossed somewhere in my Rails code, and am no longer able to reproduce my problem. I think you might have been right that I may have been using a strange Rails version (despite having 4.1.2 in my gemfile). In any case, I think this is a great answer for helping future readers troubleshoot their own oddities if anyone else runs into similar problems.

Comment: Great research to try to discover what might be causing the error. Congrats!

Comment: This indeed works, but there's a HUGE caveat here: if you are removing a column that contains a reference (like `user_id`), you probably have an index on that column, which will be automatically removed by Rails 4+ on `remove_column`. If you revert this migration, even if you specify the column type (like `:integer`), it will NOT re-add the index on the column, which can bring you a huge performance problem. So I would recommend spending a little bit more time and writing the up and down methods on the migration.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `change`, you use `up` and `down` methods to your migration:

```
def up
  remove_column :foos, :bar
end

def down
  add_column :foos, :bar, :boolean
end
```

Comment: The whole point of `change` is to not have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a bulk remove of columns, you can make the migration reversible as follows (since rails 6.1)

```rb
def change
    change_table :foobar, bulk: true do |t|
      t.remove :foo, type: :float
      t.remove :bar, type: :int
    end
  end
```