# Irreversible migration, can it be fixed? - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So i made a migration like this

```
class AddDatetimeAttrToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

on my local environment it works just fine but when i try

heroku run rake db:migrate i get an error

```
ERROR:  column "oauth_expires_at" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

When i searched it, i created a new migration like this as best practice for changing an attribute using **change**.

```
class PutDatetimeFieldToUsersExpireAtColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :users, :oauth_expires_at
    add_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

so i tried to use rake db:rollback to delete last migration and add this one informing me that the last migration is irreversible.

my question is, is there a way to actually rollback on an irreversible migration or should i just migrate using the new migration above?

Comment: Irreversible migration is irreversible, since you destroy data. You may be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723737/rails-and-postgresql-migration-change-column-type) that lets you know how to use `USING` (as suggested by the HINT) in a migration. (EDIT: changed the link to a better one)

Comment: how do i add a USING CLAUSE?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you have the following migration file:

```
class AddDatetimeAttrToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

You have already run `rake db:migrate` successfully in your dev environment.  You are running sqlite3 locally and PG on heroku, and and as a result, your `change_column` works locally, but it fails on PG because PG expects a 'using' statement.

The fix this, step 1 is to edit your migration file to add an up and down migration as suggested by Yohann above.  Yes, you should do this even though you have already raked this migration.

```
class AddDatetimeAttrToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def up
        change_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :datetime
      end
      def down
        change_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :time (or whatever type existed before datetime)
      end
    end
```

Now you can run `rake db:rollback` and avoid the irreversible migration error, but only if you HAVE NOT ADDED ADDITIONAL MIGRATIONS. If you have added additional migrations you will need to specify how far back to go using `rake db:down VERSION=2018xxxxxxx` or `rake db:rollback STEP=X`.

Now edit the migration so it plays nice with pg and sqlite3:

```
class AddDatetimeAttrToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
          def up
            change_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :datetime, using: 'oauth_expires_at::datetime'
          end
          def down
            change_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :time

        end
```

Now you should be able to rake db:migrate, push to heroku, and heroku run rake db:migrate and move on.

Finally, you should get pg working locally to match your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can define  `up` and `down` methods instead of `change` in your migration.
Here is an example:

```
def up
  connection.execute %(create or replace view name_of_the_db_view)
end

def down
  connection.execute %(drop view name_of_the_db_view)
end
```

With it you will be able to `migrate` and `rollback` the previously irreversible migration like it was a normal migration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to specify a current type of oauth_expires_at column, because at rollback Rails should know it to create the column. I mean following:

```
remove_column :users, :oauth_expires_at, :string
```

Answer (score -1):

if you dare to lose your data on your local database then you can recover from irreversible migration(by losing your database data) by doing these steps:

1- first deleting your database(assuming that you are in the development environment and just ok to delete the database in this environment - your test database will also be gone)

```
export RAILS_ENV=development


rake db:drop
```

2- Reloading your schema file:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

3- To see your current migration files:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

4- Delete the migration that you want to get rid of:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxxxx


rails destroy migration migration_name
```

5- Then you can make db:migrate to migrate your migrations.

```
rake db:migrate
```