# How do I remove id column in a reversible way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migrate

I can remove the id column with a migration action like this:

```
remove_column :my_table, :id
```

How can I make this call reversible? I want to restore the :id column with its whole capabilities when a rollback is performed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make remove\_column reversible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520550/how-do-you-make-remove-column-reversible)

Comment: You'd have to save the data away in another table and have a way to link id to your new primary key.  You could use a table that your drop later after you've decided you won't rolblack

Comment: I will not use the ID again in the future. I created the ID by mistake (forgetting to put id: false). What I need is the parameters to recreate the ID (with pk and autoincrement).